# Error in moving variables from android class to php side

Tags: java, php, android

I am currently developing an app and i have a problem in transferring the variables from android to the php script. However the connection is established. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my Java code.

```
// open a URL connection to the Servlet
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

// Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";name=\""
                    + username + "\"" + lineEnd);

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

// create a buffer of  maximum size
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// read file and write it into form...
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

while (bytesRead > 0) {
  dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
  bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
  bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   
}

// send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

And this is my php script

```
<?php
  require("config.inc.php");
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['filename']);
    $user = $_FILES['username'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, picture ) VALUES ( '1234567', $user, $file_path ) ";
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "success";

    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

The problem is in the section of setting the values and the variables are moved empty. In the database nothing is being added.

Comment: A little formatting would go a long way towards your question being seen instead of being buried in your code.

Comment: thank you for this remark i edited it and made it way less code so people can pass by it easily.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it fails is because you did not prepare your query properly:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, picture ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? ) ";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array('1234567', $user, $file_path));
```

Comment: Actually this is not the problem since it does insert properly after fixing minor syntax issue the major problem is that the image does move to the php script and i can extract while the string parameter i can not extract it :/

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaged which string are you talking about you should echo and see which one is empty

Comment: The string $user however the image is working perfectly and i can get its path.@meda

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMaged do a `var_dump($_FILES)` also you wrote the `name` attribute twice, in the second `Content-Disposition`.. are you uploading mulitple files?